# Github Markdown : Is it possible to put links under emojis?

Tags: github, hyperlink, markdown, emoji

A picture of my attempt here:

[image: A picture of my attempt here]

I know I can put links within images. But what about emojis. For example, can  emoji be used as a link?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax:

`[:smile:](http://github.com)`

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Provided above syntax is totally fine, at least in GitHub's README.md.

I just wanted to add 2 more cents:

- syntax for www: `[:memo:](https://www.google.com/)` or just copy/paste an emoji icon `[](https://www.google.com/)`
- syntax for email: `[:black_nib:](mailto:person@example.com)` or just copy/paste an emoji icon `[✒️](mailto:person@example.com)`